# Contents aren't rendering when index.html is clicked on the browser, though the CDN is applied on Sublime text

Tags: javascript, reactjs

index.css

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

index.html

<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@17/umd/react.development.js"></script>
        <script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@17/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
        <script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="root"></div>
        <script src="index.js" type="text/babel"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

index.js

ReactDOM.render(

## Hello, everyone!

, document.getElementById("root"))

The result is not showing up in the browser, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Which **React version** are you using? your render looks like **v.17** and under. if you use react **v.18^** it can give you a blank page, instead try to render it this way:

```js
const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
      <h1>Hello World</h1>
  </React.StrictMode>
);
```

Comment: i have tried this method it isn't working my version seems to be 17, I have directly created a root folder and is experimenting on it do I have to run a web engine like WAAMP to have any affect on files?

Comment: edit- do i have to run this whole bunch of code in XAAMP local server?

Comment: No engines are needed like MAMP/XAMPP. Just running a script `npm run start` or `yarn start`  should be fine.